# Pyinstaller subprocess.check_output error

Tags: python

I've bundled my app with `pyinstaller` to 2 `*.exe`

```
gui_app.exe (onefile)
config.ini
\libs (onedir)
     winservice.exe
     + all DLLs and libs
```

When I manually install service with command `winservice.exe install` everything is fine, but when I use command from GUI:

```
def svc_install(self):
    try:
        svc_inst = sb.check_output([os.getcwd()+"\libs\winservice.exe", "--startup=auto", "install"])
    except WinError as e:
        msg.showerror(e)
```

I get this error:

```
 File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
  File "gui\pagethree.py", line 24, in <lambda>
  File "gui\pagethree.py", line 35, in svc_install
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\rs_al\dev\pyxlsql\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "utils\configparse.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rs_al\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\codecs.py", line 898, in open
    file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\rs_al\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\config.ini'
```

Why it's looking for `config.ini` in `AppData`? When I display current working directory `msg.showinfo("", os.getcwd())` instead , it shows current directory with app files and dirs. I define path to `config.ini` in `winservice` code, also and I use `gui_app` to edit it.

```
self.filename = 'config.ini'
            with codecs.open(self.filename, "r", encoding="utf-8-sig") as self.config_file:
                self.config_ini.insert(tk.INSERT, self.config_file.read())
                self.config_ini.bind()

 def save_to_file(self):
        with open (self.filename, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as self.config_file:
            data = self.config_ini.get('0.0', tk.END)
            self.config_file.write(data)
```

In `configparse`(anyway it's overridden by `Pyinstaller`)

```
default_path = str(Path(__file__).parents[2])
default_config_file = str(Path(default_path+"\config.ini"))
config.read_file(codecs.open(default_config_file, encoding="utf-8-sig"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in `configparser`. I've added function to standalone `gui_app` to exclude variables cross import from main code.